# Printing a column of a 2-D List in Python

Tags: python, list

Suppose if `A = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]`

Then `A[0][:]` prints `[1, 2, 3]`

But why does `A[:][0]` print `[1, 2, 3]` again ?

It should print the column `[1, 4, 7]`, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[:]` is equivalent to copy.

`A[:][0]` is the first row of a copy of A.
`A[0][:]` is a copy of the first row of A.

The two are the same.

To get the first column: `[a[0] for a in A]`
Or use numpy and `np.array(A)[:,0]`

Answer (score 2):

When you don't specify a start or end index Python returns the entire array:

```
A[:] = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 2):

`[:]` matches the entire list.

So `A[:]` is the same as `A`. So `A[0][:]` is the same as `A[0]`.

And `A[0][:]` is the same as `A[0]`.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `[:]` just gives you a copy of **all the content** of the list. So what you are getting is perfectly  normal. I think you wanted to use this operator as you would in *numpy* or Matlab. This does not do the same in regular Python.

---

`A[0]` is `[1, 2, 3]`

Therefore `A[0][:]` is also `[1, 2, 3]`

---

`A[:]` is `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]`

Therefore `A[:][0]` is `[1, 2, 3]`

---

If you wanted the first column you should try:

```
[e[0] for e in A]
# [1, 4, 7]
```

Comment: Thanks, that was fast ! I should use Numpy array then...print(A[:,0]) should print the column if A is Numpy.

Comment: @Shanks the list comprehension is easier than using numpy though (numpy requires importing the library, that you have to extra install...).

Comment: If you don't want to bother using _numpy_ just for this, you can still do the small trick I've added at the end. See what's best for your case!

Answer (score 2):

`A[:]` returns a copy of the entire list. which is `A = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]`
`A[:][0]` Thus selects `[1, 2, 3]`.
If you want the first column, do a loop:

```
col = []
for row in A:
    col.append(row[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Problem

A is not a 2-D list: it is a list of lists.  In consideration of that:

1. `A[0]` is the first list in A:

   ```
   >>> A = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
   >>> A[0]
   [1, 2, 3]
   ```

   Consequently, `A[0][:]`: is every element of the first list:

   ```
   >>> A[0][:]
   [1, 2, 3]
   ```
2. `A[:]` is every element of A, in other words it is a copy of A:

   ```
   >>> A[:]
   [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
   ```

   Consequently, `A[:][0]` is the first element of that copy of A.

   ```
   >>> A[:][0]
   [1, 2, 3]
   ```

#### Solution

To get what you want, use numpy:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.array( [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]] )
```

`A` is now a true two-dimensional array.  We can get the first row of `A`:

```
>>> A[0,:]
array([1, 2, 3])
```

We can similarly get the first column of `A`:

```
>>> A[:,0]
array([1, 4, 7])
```

`

Answer (score 2):

A is actually a list of list, not a matrix. With `A[:][0]` You are accessing the first element (the list `[1,2,3]`) of the full slice of the list A. The `[:]` is Python slice notation (explained in [the relevant Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation)).

To get [1,4,7] you would have to use something like `[sublist[0] for sublist in A]`, which is a *list comprehension*, a vital element of the Python language.